# Is there any way to run a command while another command is already running in python-telegram-bot?

Tags: python, telegram, telegram-bot, python-telegram-bot, py-telegram-bot-api

Let's say there's an infinity loop inside the start function. while it's running... I need another command to run in the background. another function. (a stop command for an example) I tried putting it after "updater.start_polling()" but it didn't work because of a few reasons. I couldn't set up a scheduler for that.

```
def start(update: Update, context: CallbackContext) -> None:
    while true:
        context.bot.send_message(chat_id=update.effective_chat.id, text= "Choose an option. ('/option1' , '/option 2', '/...')")


def main():

    updater = Updater("<MY-BOT-TOKEN>", use_context=True)

    updater.dispatcher.add_handler(CommandHandler('start', start))

    updater.start_polling()
    updater.idle()


if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

Comment: you should rather in separated thread code which you have in start

Comment: @furas I tried doing it and it's the best way I can see. but I couldn't trigger the code when it gives an update. like... I need a listener. (I'm sure there's a way to do that but I'm not sure how)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Utilize threading

```
from time import sleep
from threading import Thread    

def start(update: Update, context: CallbackContext) -> None:
   while true:
      context.bot.send_message(chat_id=update.effective_chat.id, text= "Choose an option. ('/option1' , '/option 2', '/...')")
      sleep(.1)

def stop():
   pass # some code here

def main():

   updater = Updater("<MY-BOT-TOKEN>", use_context=True)

   updater.dispatcher.add_handler(CommandHandler('start', start))

   t1 = Thread(target=updater.start_polling)
   t2 = Thread(target=stop)
   t1.start()
   t2.start()
   updater.idle()


if __name__ == '__main__':
   main()
```

Answer (score 0):

okay, I found a way... set up a while true after start polling and make it wait for a flag to come true. when the user sends an update it triggers the function and makes the flag True. that triggers the code after "start Polling()". with a time.sleep(1) I can run both multiple commands at once